# php - How to show values in array randomly

Tags: php

I have an array with values,

```
$member[1] = "John";
$member[2] = "Mary";
$member[3] = "Berry";
$member[4] = "James";
$member[5] = "Lincoln";
```

I can show them randomly using

```
echo $member[rand(1,5)];
echo $member[rand(1,5)];
echo $member[rand(1,5)];
echo $member[rand(1,5)];
echo $member[rand(1,5)];
```

But this way, a member can show up twice or even more!
What is the correct and professional way to show them only once randomly ?

Comment: `shuffle($members); foreach($members as $member){ echo $member; }` Shuffle will randomize the order of elements in an array: [Shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consume the entire array at random order use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle).

```
shuffle($member);

foreach($member as $memberName) {
    echo $memberName;
}
```

If you want to select one or more elements from the array at random use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array-rand).

Let's say you want to select 3 members from the array at random, with the guarantee that you will never pick the same array value twice.

```
foreach(array_rand($member, 3) as $key) {
    echo $member[$key];
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was just using the OPs variable name for consistency, but I did use `$members` in the second example instead of `$member`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use shuffle()

```
$shuffle($member);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 1):

Another choice,

```
$random_keys=array_rand($member,count($member));
echo $member[$random_keys[0]];
echo $member[$random_keys[1]];
echo $member[$random_keys[2]];
echo $member[$random_keys[3]];
echo $member[$random_keys[4]];
```

Comment: Note this will approach will give you identical results to the order of the elements in `$member`, because `array_rand` gives you random selection, not random distribution. So when you want to consume the entire array in random order it's better to just use `shuffle`, but if you want limited random selection and not random distribution, `array_rand` works fine. Also, you're using `echo $a[[$random_keys[0]]` when it should be `echo $member[$random_keys[0]]`.

Comment: @Sherif Thank you for your comment. You are right... If we want to arrange entire array in random order it's better to just use `shuffle`.  We can use `array_rand` when we want to limited random selection.

Comment: It doesn't have to be limited. I'm just pointing out it's random selection and not random distribution. i.e. you could `shuffle($random_keys)` if you wanted. I may have been a bit ambiguous there with my wording. By limited I mean that `array_rand()` limits selection to the set of available keys. Such that you will never get the same key twice.